# get the class of the parent html element

Tags: jquery, html

Hi guys I'm trying to get the class of the parent element of the element that I clicked

Ex:

```
<div class="mydiv"><a href="#" class="link">Click me</a></div>
```

I want to get the class of the parent div(mydiv)

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".link").click(function(){
var div=$(this).parent().className;
alert(div);
});
});
```

it always gives me (undefined). any one can help?

Comment: *"P.S : I'm new to jquery you don't need to put a -1 for every mistake you see"* Strongly recommend leaving irrelevant things like that off your questions. If the question is asked properly, people won't downvote the question. If it isn't, it'll get downvoted at least as much with that there as without.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.parent()` gives jquery object and className is a property of DOM element so try:

```
var div=$(this).parent()[0].className; // use [0] to get the DOM element and get the property
```

or

```
var div= $(this).parent().attr("class"); //Use jquery attr to get the value of the attribute class
```

Comment: The jQuery Way™ of getting `className` would be to use `$(this).parent().prop('className')`, but it really doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.attr()` [{link}](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('.element').attr('class'); // Get class(es)
$('.element').attr('id'); // Get the ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".link").click(function(){
var div=$(this).parent().attr('class');
alert(div);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`className` is a property of HTML Elements, not jQuery objects such as would be given by `$(this).parent()`. You can use:

```
$(this).parent()[0].className;
```

which accesses the DOM object representing the object (`$(this).parent()[0]`) and then looks up the `className` property.

Note that if you have multiple classes applied to an element then the `className` property will return a string consisting of all the class names separated spaces.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className

On newer browsers, you can use the `classList` property, which makes dealing with classes easier:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList

Answer (score 1):

Try this..... `$(this).parent().attr('class');` ...m sure this will work :)

Answer (score 1):

This should get the job done :

```
var parentClass = $('#childElement').parent().attr('class');
```